# Add a “Canonical” badge awarding questions/answers that are common dupe targets

Tags: feature-request, badges, vote-to-close, duplicate-questions, badge-request

I’d like to propose a badge that rewards those that write questions that are common dupe targets. This could apply when all of these are true:

- you wrote the post

  - it’s a question OR it’s the (accepted, then most-voted) answer
- it has at least 10 (bronze), 50 (silver), or 100 (gold) questions closed as a duplicate of it

  - If questions are a duplicate of a question that is closed as a duplicate, the dupe count count transfers to the question that is the final dupe target
- it is not closed as a duplicate

Name ideas:

- Bronze: Duplicated
- Silver: Dupe Target
- Gold: Canonical

Comment: Could you elaborate on what behaviour this stimulates (that isn't already stimulated with, say, the Great Answer / Great Question badges)?

Comment: @Glorfindel It makes a badge specifically for creating dupe targets, so people will try to write better (self-answered?) questions.

Comment: But a large number of dupe targets aren't particularly good questions and answers.  They are just duplicates.

Comment: I like the idea, not sold on the badge names though (bronze and silver at least). The numbers seem a bit off to me—I'm not entirely certain but I'm guessing at least gold would be next to impossible to get on a lot of smaller sites

Answer (score 6):

**I disagree.** [Help Center > Asking](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on all SE sites clearly states

> Please [look around](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search) to see if your question has been asked before.

SE encourages users to search for duplicates and discourages asking a duplicate question. I am afraid those badges could mislead users into believing that asking a duplicate question is encouraged here.

Also, based on my experience on some sites, the more basic the question is, the more duplicate questions are asked. I don't think it is a good idea to award a user with those badges who posts common dupe targets. In addition, the more dupe targets your question and answers become, the more upvotes your posts will receive and as commented, there are other badges. A badge should be awarded based on the quality and helpfulness, not based on the number of duplicate targets.